# Google AppEngine BlobstoreService returns 500 Error

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore, http-status-code-500

Since Friday night (April 16, 2021) I started getting 500 errors serving content from the BlobstoreService.serve() method.
I have not changed anything with this code for several years.
I checked for outages but there are not any reported.
Its now April 19 and I am still seeing the 500 error.

Is anyone else seeing this or aware of any changes to this service?

Comment: Are you still seeing this error?
What does your logs say?

Comment: The problem went away after a few days.  As it turns out the BlobstoreService is being discontinued and this issue may have been a prelude to it going away completely: 

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/blobstore-ui

I have since migrated my content to the cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is over a year old, but I recently started getting these errors as well, but only in a some environments.

We mitigated the issue by redirecting to ImagesService.getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey))

But be warned, that redirection will not return the original image if no size is specified. It will, however, not expand an image to meet the size requested. So if you choose a large enough size that is bigger than most images, you should get the original image size. I believe it defaults to 512